# SonarQube version 6.2 will not start on amazon Linux

Tags: sonarqube

After rebooting our Sonar Server running an up-to-date Amazon Linux it would not start.

```
2017.01.27 10:36:42 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2017.01.27 10:36:42 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121 0.b13.29.amzn1.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.29.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process7514074371677370036properties
2017.01.27 10:36:51 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.01.27 10:36:51 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.29.amzn1.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.29.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process6553321235832962376properties
2017.01.27 10:36:54 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2017.01.27 10:36:54 ERROR app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] failed to start
2017.01.27 10:36:54 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

The above indicates you need to read `/var/log/sonar/web.log`

The postgres jar above `/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar` is a bad smell, so on a hunch I downloaded the latest version, 
which fixed the problem.

I imagine this will be fixed by the Sonar team pretty soon but this posted here in the hope that it helps.